# How to send table row data in ajax request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am new in java web techology. The image shows output table. If I click on the assign button, an ajax request will be called which will take the data if 2nd column of the same row. What can I do? TIA :) 
[image: data table]

Comment: Have a look at jquery as to how to access td text.  if you have an event handler on `Assing` then it will be something like $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)` or something

Answer (score 0):

A pure JS function could be (step by step):

```
function getDataTable(theButton){
    ...
    var theTD = theButton.parentNode;
    var theTR = theTD.parentNode;
    var brothers = theTR.childNodes; /* Including the button's td.*/
    /* Select a cell, counting  from 1 to N.*/
    brothers[/*the td-index you want*/].innerHTML = /* the value you want to set.*/
    brothers[/*the td-index you want*/].innerHTML; /* or simply get the value it already have.*/
    ...
    /*your AJAX code*/
}
```

Your button should look something like:

```
<button onclick="getDataTable(this);">Get data</button>
```